# Namespaces and the Pre-Processor

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

I’m having some trouble understanding the preprocessor and namespaces in C++. For example, consider the following program:

```
#include <iostream> 

int main() 
{
    using namespace std;

    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;

    return 0; 
}
```

So when this program is getting ready to be compiled, the preprocessor will recognize the #include directive and add the iostream file to the program so that the program will have I/O capability (ie “cout” and “endl”). Now according to my textbook the classes, functions, and variables that are a standard component of C++ compilers are placed in the namespace std.

This is confusing because if the standard functions (“cout” and “endl”) are placed in this namespace what is the purpose of iostream? I’m basically trying to understand why we need both iostream and some information about the namespace in use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strictly speaking, you do not need `using namespace std;` All it does is letting you write

```
cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
```

instead of

```
std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
```

The namespace "contains" iostream definitions (among other definitions provided by the standard C++ library) only in the sense that `std::` is implicitly "prefixed" to all names. This "contains" is different from the "contains" in "the `iostream` file contains definitions of input/output functions": the file literally contains the definitions; the `std::` namespace name is only a prefix that lets you avoid name collisions.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly the iostream file contains the actual definition for "cout", and "endl", while the namespace contains iostream definitions along with other definitions. Is the only reason to include information about the namespace (ie prefixing with std:: or stating "using namespace std;") to avoid name collision? It just seems kind of weird to have all the definitions you need already included (via the preprocessor step) and you still have to give more information about a namespace

Comment: @Ockham I wouldn't use the word "contains" for the namespace to avoid confusion. The only true containment here is "iostream contains definitions for `cout` and `endl`". Inside iostream, these definitions are *enclosed* within the `std` namespace. The "real name" (also known as "fully qualified name") of `cout` is `std::cout`. When you throw in a `using` directive, the compiler implicitly prefixes `std::` to *unqualified* names (i.e. names with no scope resolution operator `::` present) to resolve their definitions. The `using` is fully optional, though.

Comment: Also, `using namespace std;` is problematic because it pollutes the namespace, especially once you include more of the standard headers. (It's not as bad inside a function as it would be on file level, but I still don't think it's a good idea and `using std::cout;`, `using std::endl` is better.

Answer (score 1):

The header file `<iostream>` includes declarations of several useful things, including the variables `std::cout` and `std::endl`.

Without these declarations, the compiler wouldn't know what you were referring to when you write `cout << ...`.